# What's the difference between these types of air hose material?

Tags: hose

I'm looking at picking up a new piece of air hose (or 2), and I see that there are a couple of different materials that they're made out of. I currently have rubber and, I believe, PVC hoses at home, but I thought I'd ask about the difference before buying more.

I'm seeing 4 different types:

- PVC
- PVC/Rubber
- Rubber
- Polyurethane

My experience is that the PVC (I think that's what I've got - I bought it a long time ago and don't remember) is much lighter than the rubber and that the rubber gets much stiffer in the winter time and is difficult to use.

What are the advantages and drawbacks to the various types of hose material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had several kinds of hoses I like the rubber hoses best I have 1 section that is close to 40 years old it has small cracks in the outer layer and I have replaced the ends many times, I just recently purchased 2 more 50 foot section, the negative with rubber is the weight. PVC hose, this is the lightest and cheapest of the hoses it gets brittle if left in the sun. I had a 100' section of hose running into my house from my garage the hose was about 5 years old and prior to the 6 months providing air for demo and remodel work it was in ok shape, I say ok because a wonder bar was dropped on it from the 2nd floor and the hose split about 3' long ( my air supply to a ballast tank is at 150 psi then I have a regulator on the ballast tank usually set at 90) so I find the pvc won't hold up to impacts and after 6 months it got so brittle I ended up throwing it. Or over 1/2 of it.  I have had a couple of PVC hoses with rubber coating these held up better than the PVC but had failures if driven over with a wheel barrow full of brick and mortar similar to straight PVC but the rubber really made a neat "pop" when it cracked the liner. As far as poly I thought it would better when moving around and non marking. It did better than both PVC and rubber coated PVC but in cold weather it cracked it was really cold in the low teens so I go back to my old stand by of the rubber, it is heavy and cost more but it stands up to harsh environments including oil better. One place I will still use straight PVC is for roofing because it is so light but I don't plan on the hose lasting long , but I don't do many roofing jobs anymore.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I ended up getting a longer run of rubber and another shorter run of PVC. I'll use the PVC at the tool end since it's lighter and more maneuverable, and, since it's a shorter piece, if it gets ruined, it's less $ to replace.